# GL_TRIANGLE FAN Explanation

Tags: opengl

I am trying to "fill" a surface of a sphere that I drew using this algorithm here:
http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/sphere_cylinder/, the first method.

I know that `GL_QUADS` is no longer used in OpenGL 3+. SO I used `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`. Is it the same thing? The problem here is that my sphere facets are squares. So if I use `GL_TRIANGLE` then I get a weird "filling", not all the surface is covered.

Am I doing it the wrong way? How does `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` work exactly?

Comment: is that for new versions of OpenGL?

Comment: Triangle FAN is a basic primitive which share the same concept in all OpenGL versions and also Direct3D (XNA).

Comment: @TrtTrt: New version? OpenGL removed features; it didn't _change_ the ones it kept. And if you just wanted to know if it was kept, the specification and documentation all tell you that. The [3.3](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/) and [4.2](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/) documentation is _only_ for core OpenGL.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> How does GL_TRIANGLE_FAN works exactly?

The first vertex of a triangle fan acts like a hub. The vertices following connect with the previous non-starting vertex and the hub.

[image]

Comment: Is it counter clockwise in every ‚common’ implementation? (Webgl for example)

Comment: The winding order is not so much a thing about the primitive (which this question was about), but what's interpreted as the front face of a primitive. And you can switch that per your requirements. As far as Khronos graphics APIs go the *default* for OpenGL, OpenGL-ES and WebGL is counterclockwise. Vulkan doesn't have a default and face orientation winding rule must be set explicitly at pipeline creation.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a triangle strip instead of a fan.

See also this question: [gl_triangle_strip vs gl_triangle_fan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394727/gl-triangle-strip-vs-gl-triangle-fan)

Comment: I doubt that a triangle strip would help him to tessellate a sphere in one draw call. And for a single quad a triangle fan works as well as a triangle strip.

Comment: You can use a triangle strip, but you need to strategically duplicate vertices at the end of the strip to move to the next strip.  The duplicated vertices create empty triangles, which OpenGL ignores.  However, using straight-up triangles is certainly more straightforward.