# GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP vs GL_TRIANGLE_FAN

Tags: opengl, gl-triangle-strip

I need an example of a polygon that can be done only by `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` and another polygon that can be done only by `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

When knowing the difference between *Triangle Strip* and *Triangle Fan* a shape will be easy to make.

### Triangle Strip

For instance a *Triangle Strip* is a set of connected triangles which share vertices.

#### Example of Triangle Strip

Using *Triangle Strip* we will be able to get the following output, using those given vertices.

[image]

### Triangle Fan

Where a *Triangle Fan* is also a set of connected triangles, though all these triangles have a common vertex, which is the central vertex.

In OpenGL the central vertex is the first given vertex, in the *Triangle Fan*.

#### Example of Triangle Fan

Using *Triangle Fan* and the same vertices as in the other example, we will only be able to get the *colored area* as output. That is due to the importance of the arranged order of the vertices in *Triangle Fan*. **Basically,** all the vertices need to go around the central vertex.

[image]

### Conclusion

As you can see on our 2 example sets of vertices those "output shapes" are unique to both *Triangle Strip* and *Triangle Fan*.

**Note:** The image examples uses clockwise [winding order](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling#Winding_order), while in OpenGL the **front side uses counter-clockwise winding order**, i.e. the examples are *literally* facing away from the camera. This is an important detail if [face culling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling) is enabled.

#### Extra

*I made a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20268455/2470818), you can read it if you want, I actually used the same images since the questions are closely related.*

Comment: Is a fan drawn faster than a strip?

Comment: A better explanation is that the `strip` always uses the last 2 vertices of one triangle as the first 2 vertices of the next triangle. So in the strip diagram, imagine doing the first 3 triangles, then wanting to add a triangle C-E-G instead of D-E-G. Can't do that, because D-E is automatically the start of triangle 4. The result can be done with a `fan`, as there is a common vertex. Diagram of the result: [Wiki- Triangle fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_fan)

Comment: Your drawings have a clockwise ordering of the first triangle, which may be a problem for a beginner OpenGL user. CW oriented triangles will not be drawn with default OpenGL settings.

Comment: @PaulJurczak Damn, 7 years and I never noticed that. I've updated the answer and added a comment, thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

Difficult to answer in pure text. For Fan, an S shape would be impossible (in general, remember that fan is limited in that there is a point common to *every* triangle).

As for the other way around - it's a trick question. triangle_strip can do every triangle_fan polygon, although it requires a little trickery.
Consider the following polygon (ordering shown is for triangle_fan)

```
3--4--5
|\ | /|
2--1--6
   | \|
   8--7
```

This could be done as follows

```
2-----4
| \  /|
1--3/7| 
   | \|
   6--5
```

Note the overlapping polygons. If you don't allow double-sided polys or overlap, then this would be an example of a fan only poly, I suppose.

Comment: thanks! it's a perfect example. I was not considering overlapping polygons, so its a valid example.

Comment: As you said, there is no such thing as a fan-only poly for the simple reason that you can mimic a triangle fan using a triangle strip by repeating the common vertex every other vertex. If vertex 1 is to be the common vertex, do (1,)2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6, etc. Every other triangle is degenerate. (No need to specify that first "1" because the first triangle is a degenerate one.)